# Limit Max and Min on a two thumb slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a two thumb range slider to set the max value and the min value, now I realized that it's possible to go over the thumbs - max can go over min and min over max.

> I want to limit min to not go over max and max not over min

After some researched I've not seen any usefull JS.
Is there any option I can use for this one.

```js
const twoRangeSlider = (() => {
  const rangeCheck = (rangeInputs, rangeMinOutput, rangeMaxOutput) => {
    const rangeMin = rangeInputs[0].min ? rangeInputs[0].min : 0;
    const rangeMax = rangeInputs[0].max ? rangeInputs[0].max : 100;
    let rangeMinValue = parseFloat(rangeInputs[1].value);
    let rangeMaxValue = parseFloat(rangeInputs[0].value);

    rangeMinValue = Math.min(Math.max(rangeMinValue, rangeMin), rangeMaxValue);


    const rangeMinPercentage = Number(
      ((rangeMinValue - rangeMin) * 100) / (rangeMax - rangeMin));
    const rangeMaxPercentage = Number(
      ((rangeMaxValue - rangeMin) * 100) / (rangeMax - rangeMin));


    rangeInputs[0].style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #000 ${rangeMaxPercentage}%, #c4c8ca ${rangeMaxPercentage}%)`;
    rangeInputs[1].style.background = `linear-gradient(to right,#c4c8ca ${rangeMinPercentage}%, transparent ${rangeMinPercentage}%)`;


  };

  const bindComponent = (item) => {
    const rangeInputs = item.querySelectorAll('.js-two-range-slider-input');
    const rangeMinOutput = item.querySelector('.js-two-range-slider-min-value');
    const rangeMaxOutput = item.querySelector('.js-two-range-slider-max-value');

    item.addEventListener("input", () => {
      rangeCheck(rangeInputs, rangeMinOutput, rangeMaxOutput);
    });

    rangeCheck(rangeInputs, rangeMinOutput, rangeMaxOutput);
  };

  const init = () => {
    const rootEl = document.getElementsByClassName("js-two-range-slider");
    [...rootEl].forEach((item) => bindComponent(item));
  };

  return {
    init
  };
})();

twoRangeSlider.init();
```

```css
.two-range-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 4px;
  width: 164px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.two-range-slider__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  appearance: none;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  outline: 0;
}

.two-range-slider__value {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 19px;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.two-range-slider__input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two-range-slider__input::-moz-range-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two-range-slider__output {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 140%;
  top: -15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.range-slider__value {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-range-slider js-two-range-slider">
  <input type="range" value="80" min="10" max="100" step="1" class="two-range-slider__input js-two-range-slider-input">
  <input type="range" value="30" min="10" max="100" step="1" class="two-range-slider__input js-two-range-slider-input">

  <div class="two-range-slider__output">
    <p class="minmax">Min</p><input class="two-range-slider__value js-two-range-slider-min-value" type="number" value="30" min="10" max="100" step="1"></input>
    <p class="maxmin">Max</p><input style="right: -5px;" class="two-range-slider__value js-two-range-slider-max-value" type="number" value="80" min="10" max="100" step="1"></input>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When changing a sliders position (`change`-event) just get the value of the changing sliders (`input.value`) and change the opposite sliders min or max to the value (+/- 1) from the first slider.

Comment: @Christopher sorry, is it possible to extend your solution ? I don't understand it 100% - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I shortened your example a bit to show what i meant in my comment.

```js
const twoRangeSlider = (() => {

  const bindComponent = (item) => {
    const rangeInputs = item.querySelectorAll('.js-two-range-slider-input');

    item.addEventListener("input", ({ target }) => {
      const [ right, left ] = rangeInputs;
      if (target == right) {
        left.value = Math.min(+right.value -1, +left.value);
      } else {
        right.value = Math.max(+left.value +1, +right.value);
      }

    });

  };

  const init = () => {
    const rootEl = document.getElementsByClassName("js-two-range-slider");
    [...rootEl].forEach((item) => bindComponent(item));
  };

  return {
    init
  };
})();

twoRangeSlider.init();
```

```css
.two-range-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 4px;
  width: 164px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.two-range-slider__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  appearance: none;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  outline: 0;
}

.two-range-slider__value {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 19px;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.two-range-slider__input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two-range-slider__input::-moz-range-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two-range-slider__output {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 140%;
  top: -15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.range-slider__value {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-range-slider js-two-range-slider">
  <input type="range" value="80" min="10" max="100" step="1" class="two-range-slider__input js-two-range-slider-input">
  <input type="range" value="30" min="10" max="100" step="1" class="two-range-slider__input js-two-range-slider-input">

  <div class="two-range-slider__output">
    <p class="minmax">Min</p><input class="two-range-slider__value js-two-range-slider-min-value" type="number" value="30" min="10" max="100" step="1">
    <p class="maxmin">Max</p><input style="right: -5px;" class="two-range-slider__value js-two-range-slider-max-value" type="number" value="80" min="10" max="100" step="1">
  </div>

</div>
```